# Counter to use with if condition in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Actually i am comparing two data tables. data table1 have the columns called **EmployeeNo**, **IC**.data table1 have the columns called **EmployeeNo**, **IC** and **RelationID** . So if the IC value in the second data table is empty, i can replace the IC value from data table1 only if the EmployeeNo of both table matches.

```
 var Check = child.MemberIC;
 if (Check == "" || Check.Length < 12)
 {
  foreach (DataRow row1 in dataTable.Rows)
  {
   foreach (DataRow row2 in dataTable1.Rows)
   {
     if (row1["EmployeeNo"].ToString() == row2["EmployeeNo"].ToString())
     {
       var ss = row1["MemberIc"].ToString();
       if (row2["RelationId"].ToString() == "4")
        {
           newRow1["MemberIC"] = ss + "C";  **//How can i add the counter value with this value (ss + "C").**
        }
         else
        {   
           newRow1["MemberIC"] = ss + "S";                                               
        }
     }                                                            
   }
  }
 }
```

So, How can i add the counter values with the Member IC. Lets say if i have two same employeeID in data table 2 with empty MemberIC. So when i copy the MemberIC value from data table 1. The 1st row of data table 2 MemberIC value will be like ss + "C"+counter and The 2nd row of data table 2 MemberIC value will be like ss + "C"+counter++

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following logic to add counter...
If you only want to add counter if there are more than 1 matching records.. try following

```
var Check = child.MemberIC;
 if (Check == "" || Check.Length < 12)
 {
  foreach (DataRow row1 in dataTable.Rows)
  {
  var counter = 0;
  var matchingRows = 
            dataTable1.Select()
           .Count(r=> r["EmployeeNo"].ToString() == row1["EmployeeNo"].ToString());
   if(matchingRows > 1)
    counter +=1;
   foreach (DataRow row2 in dataTable1.Rows)
   {
     if (row1["EmployeeNo"].ToString() == row2["EmployeeNo"].ToString())
     {
       var ss = row1["MemberIc"].ToString();
       if (row2["RelationId"].ToString() == "4")
        {
           var memberIC = ss + "C" + (counter > 0 ? counter : "");
           newRow1["MemberIC"] = memberIC ;  **//How can i add the counter value with this value (ss + "C").**
        }
         else
        {   
           newRow1["MemberIC"] = ss + "S";                                               
        }
      if(counter > 0)
         counter++;
     }                                                            
   }
  }
 }
```